# why the option of hidden was given to overflow by css working group?

Tags: html, css

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Flow_Layout_and_Overflow#controlling_overflow)

it says quote

> There are other values that control how overflow content behaves. To hide overflowing content use a value of hidden. This may cause some of your content to not be visible.

so what was the rationale for css to give suggestion that some of your content to not be visible and define overflow with a `hidden` option?

Comment: Unless someone from the working group pops in and offers an answer, there's no way to answer a question (without speculation) about others' motives or rationale.